# Golang testing: "no test files"

Tags: testing, go, terminal

I'm creating a simple test within my package directory called reverseTest.go

```
package main

import "testing"

func TestReverse(t *testing.T) {
    cases := []struct {
        in, want string
    }{
        {"Hello, world", "dlrow ,olleH"},
        {"Hello, 世界", "界世 ,olleH"},
        {"", ""},
    }

    for _, c := range cases {
        got := Reverse(c.in)
        if got != c.want {
            t.Errorf("Reverse(%q) == %q, want %q", c.in, got, c.want)
        }
    }
}
```

whenever i try to run it the output is

```
exampleFolder[no test files]
```

this is my go env

```
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCHAR="6"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/juan/go"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/lib/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/lib/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
TERM="dumb"
CC="gcc"
GOGCCFLAGS="-g -O2 -fPIC -m64 -pthread"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: for `Go testing` your Test file should have `**_test.go` `example.go` should have corresponding`example_test.go`

Answer (score 191, accepted):

Files containing tests should be called `name_test`, with the `_test` suffix. They should be alongside the code that they are testing.

To run the tests recursively call `go test -v ./...`

From [How to Write Go Code](http://golang.org/doc/code.html#Testing):

> You write a test by creating a file with a name ending in `_test.go` that contains functions named `TestXXX` with signature `func (t *testing.T)`. The test framework runs each such function; if the function calls a failure function such as `t.Error` or `t.Fail`, the test is considered to have failed.

Comment: my file did end in _test.go. fixing the issue for me required removing a re-definition of TestMain in the new test file that I added to the package. I also had to change directory into the package folder itself and run `go test` from there instead of running it from the root directory

Comment: @thwd Test methods don't need to be (and many times shouldn't be) in the same package as the tested code.

Comment: The file containing test can't be named only `_test.go`. It should be at least one character before underscore like `a_test.go`.

Answer (score 130):

It's possible you don't have any test files in the root package and running `go test -v` does not test sub-packages, only the root package.

For example

```
.
├── Dockerfile
├── Makefile
├── README.md
├── auth/
│   ├── jwt.go
│   ├── jwt_test.go
├── main.go
```

As you see there are no test files in the root package, only the main.go file. You will get "no test files."

The solution is to test all packages within the current working directory, recursively

```
go test -v ./...
```

Or if you use [govendor](https://github.com/kardianos/govendor)

```
govendor test +local
```

Or you can specify which package (directory) to test

```
go test -v ./packagename
```

Or test a package recursively

```
go test -v ./packagename/...
```

Answer (score 22):

Your test function within your _test file must start with the prefix "Test"

GOOD:

```
func TestName (
```

BAD:

```
func NameTest (
```

*This function will not be executed as a test and results with the reported error*

Comment: To add to this it has to be `Test` followed by an capital letter or underscore etc. You can't have `TestmyFunction()`. This bit me.

Answer (score 6):

To run all the tests use below command

```
> go test ./...
//For verbose output use -v flag
> go test -v ./...
```

Answer (score 4):

I faced same problem.
In addition to previous answers i find an issue when impossible to run test if your package's folder name is `testing`.

Terminal demonstration of the issue below:

**with `testing` folder name:**

```
~/go/src/testing$ go test
?       testing [no test files]
```

**without `testing` folder name:**

```
~/go/src/testing_someothername$ go test
PASS
ok      testing_someothername   0.089s
```

In my case it was helpful

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem. I fixing them by appending various packages

go test -v ./ ./2ndpackage ./3rdpackage ./4thpackages

this solved the issue.

Also I added "_" between Test keyword and function name
Test_FuncName

Answer (score 0):

`no test files` mean you need to rename your test file to reflect the file you want to test.
**Example**
*main.go
main_test.go*

Where main.go is the file containing your code. main_test.go is the file containing your test code.

Answer (score -1):

I'm also occur this question. When I remove `func TestMain(t *testing.T)`, it works ok!

Comment: It's not clear how this answer addresses the original question. Could you add some more context?